# Question about EJS template engine for NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I'm using nodejs and EJS template engine...

if i do:

```
ejs.render(str, { cache: true, filename: 'index', locals: { test: "Text Text Text Text Text" }});
```

where **str** is the code to render...It will cache the code, ok, Perfect!

the question is. why do i have to pass the str for every request if it has been cached? (i read it using 'fs' module).... at the moment I read the file and pass it to .render().

Why do i have to read the file if it has been cached? can i optimize it?

Comment: Why don't you use the `url` property instead?

Comment: @Raynes what? i don't understand you